# Magento connect manager page just shows "Permission denied for write to" (Magento 1.5.1.0)

Tags: permissions, magento-connect-manager, magento-1.5.1

One of our client wanted to upgrade existing Magento website which is **Magento 1.5.1.0**. I was able to setup the website in our local environment successfully but when I try to navigate to the "**Magento Connect Manager**" from Magento admin, it just shows "Permission denied for write to". But it did not mention which file/folder. I tried to check the logs, But I did not see any updates related to this in the log files.

I tried to search magento.stackexchange.com for a solution but nothing helped me so far.

Can someone please let me know what is the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give proper permission to `downloader` folder in root of magento.

after gives permission you can access magento connect manager without any error.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried to set various levels of permissions, but it did not work yet to me :(

Comment: I just set write permission to the root folder & it worked. I believe it is not good practice to set write permission to the root folder. I will wait for some more time if someone has a correct solution. I just upvoted your answer as it helped me temporarily to fix the issue. Thanks @Dip :)

Comment: @manian Glad to know its helps to you. You can see more about proper permission from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).

Comment: @manian Please accept answer if its work so it can help to other as well